# Getting SolidColorBrush from a string

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to set the foreground of a textblock on the backend using a string ( something like "Red")

I've tried this:

```
ColorText.Foreground = new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(colors[color2].ToString());
```

However, it doesn't seem to be recognizing `BrushConvert()`. I've included `System.Windows.Media` but it still can't be found.

Is there another way to go about doing this?

Comment: Are you referencing `PresentationCore`?

Comment: Mike Precup is right, System.Windows.Media is the namespace, but PresentationCore is the DLL that you need to reference in your project, are you referencing that DLL?

Comment: I can't seem to find it...

Comment: What type of project do you have in VS2012 for this issue?

Comment: its a windows phone panorama app.

Answer (score 1):

`BrushConverter` isn't available in windows phone. You could build up a dictionary of colors then pass the color you want to `SolidColorBrush` ctor with a helper method.

```cs
public static class ColorsHelper {
  private static readonly Dictionary<string, Color> dict =
        typeof(Colors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
        .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => (Color)prop.GetValue(null, null));

  public static Color FromName(string name) {
    return dict[name];
  }
}

ColorText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(ColorsHelper.FromName("Red"));
```

Make sure the above dictionary uses `System.Windows.Media.Color` struct and `System.Windows.Media.Colors` class. I believe there are a few `Color` types around so type in the whole namespace if necessary or rename it.