# Return a SolidColorBrush from a custom color string

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have this line and it works but how can i return a custum color string for example "#2228D4"

```
return (Boolean)value ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
```

It's a Windows Phone 8 Application, so I can't use WPF's `ColorConverter`.

Comment: The code shows the opposite of the question. Do you want to create a brush from a hex string or do you already have a `Color` or `Brush` object and want to get is hex value?

Comment: Also, are you working on a Windows Forms or WPF application? The classes are different, eg there is a System.Drawing.Color and System.Windows.Media.Color

Comment: If value is true the background is Red if value is false the background is Yellow. This line works, but i want to return this color "#2228D4" when value is true! And it is for a Windows Phone 8 application.

Comment: The I suggest you reword the question. Also, you haven't specified whether you use WPF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the below method to Convert ColorString(hex code) to Color object.

```
    public Color ConvertStringToColor(String hex)
    {
        //remove the # at the front
        hex = hex.Replace("#", "");

        byte a = 255;
        byte r = 255;
        byte g = 255;
        byte b = 255;

        int start = 0;

        //handle ARGB strings (8 characters long)
        if (hex.Length == 8)
        {
            a = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            start = 2;
        }

        //convert RGB characters to bytes
        r = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        g = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        b = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
    }
```

And you can return brush using the below code

```
(Boolean)value ? new SolidColorBrush(ConvertStringToColor("FFFF0000")) : new SolidColorBrush(ConvertStringToColor("FF00FF00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're on phone you don't have access to BrushConverter.  Do it by breaking the hex down and assigning it to each component instead:

```
var color = new Color() {R = 0x22, G = 0x28, B = 0xD4};
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

Obviously, keep a reference to brush rather than recreating it over and over :)

Comment: I tried that before but BrushConverter gives errors.

Comment: The type or namespace BrushConverter does not exist in the current... But there is no BrushConverter namespace.

Comment: add PresentationCore.dll as reference

Comment: And what does that do?

Comment: gives access to the BrushConverter namespace, because the code is implemented in this specific library. The error will be removed and the above code should then work fine.

Comment: Ok are you sure it works for Windows Phone apps? Because i cannot find it. project->add reference->?

Comment: No it doesnt work with windows phone. You stated WPF in your tag. For a windows phone solution try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257780/getting-solidcolorbrush-from-a-string

Comment: Updated answer to reflect Windows Phone.

Comment: Hmm that gives me no Color back! It gives this string back #002228D4